# What estimators does seaborn support

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, seaborn

Seaborn allows the user to input "estimator" variable in its various plots, for example:
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html

I understand that the estimator should be a function of "vector" to "scalar" i.e. "mean" takes vector to and outputs a scalar (it's average value).

So far, I found "mean" and "sum" to be valid estimators, while "median" is not. Are there any other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many numpy functions can be used directly, for example `np.median`. `mean` is supported as `np.mean`.  `len`, `sum`, `max` and `min` are built-in python functions and work without being imported from a library.

You can also provide your own function. For example `estimator=lambda x: sum(xi*xi for xi in x)`. Or `lambda x: np.percentile(x, 95)`.

Further note that many seaborn functions draw a confidence interval, calculated via "bootstrapping", which doesn't play well with all functions. You can set `ci=None` to suppress the confidence interval.